# Call to Google Geocode API within Jersey REST Service causes internal 400 error

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I got an issue with trying to access Google Geocode API inside a jersey REST service invocation in my backend.
When I do that, it causes an internal HTTP 400 error on the server
However, invoking the Geocode API either directly through the browser or a client call works
In addition, calling a jersey REST service which calls another jersey Rest service also works
A direct call to anything works. Nesting a jersey service inside another jersey service works. But Nesting a Google API invocation inside a jersey service fails.

Call to location service ("A")

```
JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient();

JerseyWebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api").path("tournaments").path("location");

JerseyInvocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

String input = "10621 Braddock Road – Ste B, Fairfax, VA 22032";

Response response = invocationBuilder
                .post(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Location Service: ("B")

```
@POST
@Path("/location")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@CrossOrigin
public Response getLatLngFromAddress(String address) {
    LatLng latlng = LocationUtility.geocode(address);

    return Response.status(200).entity(latlng).build();     
}
```

Direct Invocation of Location Utility Geocoder ("C")

```
String address = "10621 Braddock Road – Ste B, Fairfax, VA 22032";

LatLng latlng= LocationUtility.geocode(address); 

System.out.println(latlng);
```

Geocoding function that invokes Google Geocode API ("D")

```
public static LatLng geocode(String address) {
    String address_key = address.replace(' ', '+');                 
    String API_key = "***hidden***";            

    String request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address_key + "&key=" + API_key;
    JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient();

    JerseyWebTarget webTarget = client.target(request);

    JerseyInvocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response response = invocationBuilder
            .get(Response.class);

    if (response.getStatus()/100 != 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.readEntity(String.class);

    LatLng latlng = null;

    try {
        JSONObject geocode = new JSONObject(output);
        JSONArray results = geocode.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject address_components = (JSONObject) results.get(0);
        JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) address_components.get("geometry");
        JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
        latlng = new LatLng(location.getDouble("lat"), location.getDouble("lng"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return latlng;
}
```

Call within a call sample test ("E")

```
//call within a call sample test
JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient();

JerseyWebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api").path("test").path("func1");

JerseyInvocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);


Response response = invocationBuilder
    .get(Response.class);

if (response.getStatus()/100 != 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + response.getStatus());
}

System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(output);
```

Call within a call two test service endpoints ("F")

```
@GET
@Path("/func1")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@CrossOrigin
public Response testFunc1() {
    System.out.println("1st service invoked");
    String response = "";

    response = TestDAO.callSecondService();

    return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
}

@GET
@Path("/func2")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@CrossOrigin
public Response testFunc2() {
    System.out.println("2nd service invoked");
    String response = "";

    response = TestDAO.getMessage();

    return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
}
```

Call within a call test functions: ("G")

```
public static String callSecondService() {

    JerseyClient client = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient();

    JerseyWebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api").path("test").path("func2");

    JerseyInvocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();


    Response response = invocationBuilder
            .get(Response.class);

    if (response.getStatus()/100 != 2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);

    return output;
}

public static String getMessage() {
    return "Success!"; 
}
```

C-D succeeds
E-F-G succeeds
A-B-D fails and prints the stacktrace below on the server console

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
at utilities.LocationUtility.geocode(LocationUtility.java:38)
at services.TournamentAlphaService.getLatLngFromAddress(TournamentAlphaService.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Update:

Call within call test (E-F-G) works properly when the following line

`WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/arenamaster-backend/api").path("test").path("func3");`
Is replaced by this:
`WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes");`

Comment: Why don't you try to read the body of the response to see if there is any kind of message telling you what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the body revealed that Google Geocode API doesn't accept non-UTF-8 character encoding. I had to change this one line to make it work:

```
String request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + new URLEncoder().encode(address_key, Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8")) + "&key=" + API_key;
```